# image GET request with production website

Tags: html, css, ftp

I just got a domain for my personal website. Its still very  much so a work in progress but one thing that instantly caught my attention was that the logo image will not show up in the browser when viewed from the site. It works on localhost, and I can see the image perfectly using the FTP image browser on DreamHost.

Also, my other images are showing up fine and they were all made in the same program and saved as the same type, ect. I have no idea what the problem could be. It appears the GET request for the image is not successful. Here is my site: www.daemondeveloper.com

What could it be?

P.s. View with chrome or Firefox, I haven't altered the CSS to work with IE yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server's file system is not case insensitive. You're requesting `ddlogo.png` and the file is called `ddLogo.png`.

Answer (score 1):

The image name is "ddLogo.png" not "ddlogo.png". Fix your html and you will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. It appears that using my localhost XAMPP, file names are not case sensitive, but when using DreamHost it is. I just had to change the href to reference the exact file name and it worked :)